# Can I only retrieve an element of an objectset if i call save changes?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have the following code:

```
context.MyEntities.AddObject(new Entity() { Id = 1 });
var entity = context.MyEntities.Where(e => e.Id == 1).FirstOrDefault();
```

I didn't call save changes yet, so i'm trying to retrieve the object that i added, but the `entity` is null. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

With Randolf answer, i reach the following solution:

```
context.MyEntities.AddObject(new MyEntity() { Id = 1 });
var entity = this.context
                 .ObjectStateManager
                 .GetObjectStateEntries(System.Data.EntityState.Added)
                 .Select(e => e.Entity)
                 .OfType<MyEntity>()
                 .Where(e => e.Id == 1)
                 .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 3):

ObjectContext.EntitySet will only get the entities with EntityKeys for us.   For newly inserted entities, they only have a temp entity key until SaveChanges() is called.   For detail, please see the [Entity Keys and Added Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283139.aspx) section in Working with Entity Keys (Entity Framework).

If you want to get the entities before they are saved into the database, please consider using context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(…) method.   With this method, we can get all the Added/Modified/Deleted entity state entries and entities before .SaveChanges() is called.